# How define an input layer for a transpose convolution

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using tensorflow and keras to build a neural network.

I want to use a transpose convolution with `keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose` ([Definition in Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2dtranspose))

I used this [tutorial](https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python#step-7) and I defined my network as follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose

sess = tf.Session()

batch_size = 20

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters = (batch_size,1,2700, 1),kernel_size = (2700,1), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (1,1,1,1)))
```

There is the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-01a3b17fa36f> in <module>()
     11 model = Sequential()
     12 
---> 13 model.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters = (batch_size,1,2700, 1),kernel_size = (2700,1), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (1,1,1,1)))

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py in add(self, layer)
    465                 # and create the node connecting the current layer
    466                 # to the input layer we just created.
--> 467                 layer(x)
    468 
    469             if len(layer._inbound_nodes[-1].output_tensors) != 1:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    573                 # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible
    574                 # with the input_spec specified in the layer constructor.
--> 575                 self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
    576 
    577                 # Collect input shapes to build layer.

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    472                                      self.name + ': expected ndim=' +
    473                                      str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
--> 474                                      str(K.ndim(x)))
    475             if spec.max_ndim is not None:
    476                 ndim = K.ndim(x)

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_transpose_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5
```

Nevertheless, my input has a dimension 4 (`input_shape = (1,1,1,1)`)

How can I define the input correctly then add some layers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2dtranspose) of Conv2DTranspose you can see that `filters` is a positional argument and is supposed to be an integer. This integer specifies the number of filters you want in your layer.
The next parameter is `kernel_size` (also positional) which specifies the shape of your filter. 
I think what you were looking for is :

```
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(n_filt, (2700, 1), activation='relu' input_shape = (1, 1, 1,)))
```

where `n_filt` is the number of transposed convolution filters in your layer.

Notes :

- Don't provide the batch dimension in the `input_shape` argument, or use `batch_input_shape` instead.
  *Edit to clarify* : If your data batch has dimensions `(batch_size, dim1, dim2, dim3)`, you should pass either `input_shape = (dim1, dim2, dim3, )` (Notice the comma before the last whitespace) or `batch_input_shape = (batch_size, dim1, dim2, dim3)`. I recommend using `input_shape` as you won't have any constraints on the batchsize you want to use.
- Positional arguments cannot be specified with keywords i.e don't use `filters = ...` in the function call if `filters` is a positional argument.

Comment: Which version of Keras do you use? This works fine in keras 2.2.0 with TF 1.8.0.
Can you show me the exact call you're making please?

Comment: Exact call: `model.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, (2700, 1), activation='relu', input_shape = (1, 1, 1, 1)))`

Comment: I used keras 2.1.5 and tensorflow 1.8.0 ; I updated keras, but there is still the same error...

Comment: You shouldn't provide the batch dimension in `input_shape`. Change to `input_shape = (1, 1, 1, )`